# Page Number in Lyx

Tags: windows, pdf, lyx, page-numbering

I would like to know how one would go about finding if you have started another page in Lyx.

Is there anyway within the Lyx GUI to show where a new page will begin or end ?

At the moment ..I am compiling a PDF and then adding 'page breaks' e.t.c from.

Cheers

B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this. The reason is because `LyX` would have to continually compile your document and parse the `LaTeX` log. `LyX` renders elements differently than `LaTeX` does (although you can use instant preview for some things).

Further, most `LaTeX` users would advise you not to insert page breaks manually. An advantage of `LaTeX` is that if you set it up correctly, you can just write without thinking about where page breaks or figures are.

Comment: Thanks for reply ....after some web searching I have found the needspace package which automatically does this operation of moving paragraphs to the new page. However, today it suddenly does work anymore...do you have any tips ?? I have already entered the correct commands into the preamble